# Maven command to exclude nothing despite exclude entry in pom

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin

Which maven command can be used to execute all tests despite there is `<exclude>` entry under `surefire` plugin configuration in `pom.xml` file?

For example - Following is section from `pom.xml` but i do not want to exclude `TestA.java`. Which maven command can be used?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>**/TestA.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What does "via maven command" mean? What is the other way?

Comment: Question has been edited to make it more clear. Please post here if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a profile to your pom.xml

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>all-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude></exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

This profile overwrites the excludes section for surefire plugin. 
Simply activate the profile via:

```
mvn clean install -Pall-tests
```